# Brackets and Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, web

Running this on a localhost, everything ran fine. Now, when running it on a web server, I'm getting parse errors regarding the [] in the first line. Is this not a legitimate way to declare an array in PHP?

```
function render($template, $values = [])
{
    // if template exists, render it
    if (file_exists("../templates/$template"))
    {
        // extract variables into local scope
        extract($values);
        // render template
        require("../templates/$template");
    }
```

Comment: Depends on php version (php 5.4 + for `[]`).

Answer (score 1):

In [PHP 5.4 and later](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), you can now define an array using `[]`. Everything else about syntax is the same

```
$var = array('key' => 'val');
```

PHP 5.4 and later

```
$var = ['key' => 'var'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The bracket syntax is available starting from PHP 5.4 onwards. Try `array()` instead of `[]`.